# Different exception-throwing behavior of IEnumerator.Current and IEnumerator<T>.Current

Tags: c#, ienumerator

I got an enumerator by calling `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`, I then called it's `MoveNext()` until it returned false, and then accessed its `Current` property. To my surprise, no exception was thrown.

Digging MSDN, I found that the non-generic version [will throw if `Current` is accessed after `MoveNext()` returned false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx), whereas the generic version [will not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Can someone explain this difference?

Comment: Does the down-voter care to explain what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of the generic enumerator is *undefined*, anything is possible and it is ultimately up to the collection type to define what *undefined* is going to mean.

But they can do something reasonable beyond throwing, the generic enumerators know the type of the collection object.  So they can return `default(T)`.

The non-generic enumerators don't have that luxury, they could only return null or `new object()`.  ArrayList in fact has code that reserves a static object for just this purpose.  But doesn't actually use it, looks like they changed their mind after usability testing.  Returning either is going to make the client code fail with a very unpleasant exception, NullReferenceException or InvalidCastException.  Exceptions that can also be raised in normal usage of those collections so there's very little hint to the actual cause of the mishap.  So they don't, they throw InvalidOperationException instead.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, this curiosity has been noted many times - but ultimately, after `MoveNext()` has returned `false`, you should consider the value of `Current` an undefined behaviour. If you do that: there is no issue here. Just: *don't access `Current` here* - then it doesn't matter whether it is "the last known value" vs "the default value of that type" vs "throws an exception".

Additionally, note that since the exception is thrown by the *implementation*, it is also entirely possible for an implementation of the generic API to throw, and for the non-generic API to not throw. As an example of the latter - iterator blocks *do not throw here*:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        IEnumerator<int> typed = GetInts();
        typed.MoveNext();
        Console.WriteLine(typed.MoveNext());
        int i = typed.Current;

        IEnumerator untyped = GetInts();
        untyped.MoveNext();
        Console.WriteLine(untyped.MoveNext());
        object o = untyped.Current;
    }

    static IEnumerator<int> GetInts()
    {
        yield return 4;
        yield break;
    }
```

Comment: Would have accepted both if I could :). I accepted Hans' for explaining the rational behind this behavior.

Comment: I totally agree. I think that throwing when accessing a public property is bad manners. I prefer `null`. Could this all be to avoid value-type boxing?

Comment: @bavaza not really, no; a `null` is not boxed

Comment: @bavaza it should be noted; the whole `IEnumerator` API was *basically* a bit screwy... just look at `Reset()`, which is ***completely*** useless (at least, to any sane interpretation)